# Why do two loggers can behave differently?

Tags: python, logging

I have two `loggings.Logger` instances I'm testing in IPython. They do not have any handler, but rely on propagating the message towards the `root` logger, from which they are both descendents. One of them produces the expected output message, whereas the other produces nothing, and it should. This is driving me crazy. How can I figure out what's happening?

In commands:

```
logger_a = logging.getLogger("test")
logger_b = logging.getLogger("test2")

logger_a.warning("warning")  # prints out nothing  WHY???

ogger_b.warning("warning")  # prints the text below
20210616_180404:test2:WARNING:warning

# they equally have no handlers, but propapate towards root
logger_a.handlers == logger_b.handlers  # returns True, in both cases is []
logger_a.propagate  # returns True  
logger_b.propagate  # returns True

logger_a.parent
<RootLogger root (DEBUG)>  

logger_a.parent is logger_b.parent  # returns True

logger_a.parent.handlers
[<StreamHandler <stdout> (DEBUG)>]
```

Note that I'm running things in the terminal, so at this point I can not get a minimal example that reproduces this issue. Therefore my question is more in the line of: how can I **figure out the current difference** between these two, in principle equivalent, loggers?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a self-contained script based on your post:

```
import logging

logger_a = logging.getLogger("test")
logger_b = logging.getLogger("test2")
logger_a.warning("warning1")
logger_b.warning("warning2")
assert logger_a.handlers == logger_b.handlers
assert logger_a.propagate
assert logger_b.propagate
assert logger_a.parent is logger_b.parent
print(logger_a.parent.handlers)
```

This prints out

```
warning1
warning2
[]
```

Note how both lines are printed, and there are no handlers on the root.

This means there has to be something else about your particular configuration we don't know about.

Is it possible there's a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) configured on either logger, or the root perhaps? Certainly something seems to have configured the root logger's handlers that you're not showing us.

Comment: Yes, there is something missing. My question tries to ask for hints or tools to figure out what is missing, since these are the command about #2500 in my session, I can not easily reduce this to a minimal example that reproduces the problem. There must be something I didn't check with the introspective commands I have tried so far. All I can add to my question is that I didn't configure any filter.

Comment: Well, if you've run 2500 commands in an interactive session, who knows, you might be running a version of `logging` from the outer space, or you may have replaced your `sys.stderr` object with something that only prints every other line.

Comment: Well, the fact that both loggers share parent (‘root’), and that at least one of them produces output rules out many crazy possibilities, among them that there is something I broke in the root logger and handler. There is nothing wrong with the general configuration. Only with how messages are transmitted through the loggers hierarchy.